# How to manually get an instance of a dependency in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I have an object reportsService, which for each call it make's, it initialises a new object called serviceCall. Each method needs to instantiate it's own instance of serviceCall.

Is using $injector.get() the correct way to do this?

```
app.factory('reportsService', ['$injector', function ($injector) {
    var o = {};
    o.getServiceCall = function () {
        return $injector.get('serviceCall');
    };
    o.getOriginCompositionData = function (ajaxOptions) {
        ajaxOptions.url = '/test/SpiderRequestOriginComposition';
        o.getServiceCall().initialize(ajaxOptions);
    };
    o.getExeuctionTimeData = function (ajaxOptions) {
        ajaxOptions.url = '/test/SpiderRequestExeuctionTime';
        o.getServiceCall().initialize(ajaxOptions);
    };
    o.getCacheCompositionData = function (ajaxOptions) {
        ajaxOptions.url = '/test/SpiderRequestCacheComposition';
        o.getServiceCall().initialize(ajaxOptions);
    };
    return o;
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply inject a second parameter called "serviceCall" after (or I guess instead of) "$injector" and use that. It'll be captured in closure and useable from any of your "o" function.

Comment: I wanted to do this, but if I include it as a parameter in my factory declaration, I only get one instance of it right? Because I need a different instance for each method...

Comment: Even with $injector.get, it's the same instance. In Angular (unlike Guice for example that has different "scopes") anything injected is a singleton.

Comment: It's actually kind of confusing in my opinion -- whether you use a factor or service, it's only ever instantiated once. Makes me wonder why "factory" even exists.

Comment: Thanks for the help, what I don't get now, is how  you create an object which isn't a singleton, but still doesn't pollute the global namespace lol

Comment: Have created a new question for this, refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321915/how-can-i-create-an-angular-js-service-that-isnt-a-singleton